# Power button broken and can't switch on phone

Tags: root-access, usb-debugging, htc-one-mini

I have HTC One mini. Power button is broken and can not turn it on. Phone is not rooted and unfortunately usb debugging is not turned on. Any ideas what to do? Or at least how to enable usb debugging?

I tried ./adb reboot but it can not find device

Comment: I don't know if your phone has that feature but why don't you try plugging in a charger to turn your screen on and then turn on the "raise to turn on screen" feature in the settings.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will really help you out or not but it is worth a try.
Make sure you have fastboot and USB driver for your phone is installed on your PC

Connect the a USB cable to your phone and keep on pressing the volume down button while the phone is booting.
If you are able to access the fastboot mode then you are saved and you can try `fastboot reboot` command.

If your phone is not entering into fastboot mode then go to a nearby shop and get the power button fixed. I think there is no other way you can turn on your phone.

Comment: Is this not a cat chasing her own tail? How would you boot into fastboot mode without a working power button and if power button already works somehow , then why boot into fastboot mode at all? Let it simply boot straight into Android OS in that case.

Comment: when you charge your phone, your phone boots and runs some code. Remember you can see image representation of charging.
The answer holds true for me when I was using a Xperia mini pro phone. The Mini Pro used to go via proper booting sequence and when it senses a charger or a USB cable in power off mode it was entering only to charging mode and was not turning on the phone.

it's worth giving a try than sitting idle and just watching the phone.

Comment: Thanks man, but it did not work.